# How does one go about chaining several ChannelFuture objects with Netty?

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty

I have a hashmap that contains ip/port information and a message that has to be sent to the whole list.
So I decided to create a small method that accepts the hashmap and the message and does this. It looks something like this:

```
public static ChannelFuture sendMessageTo(Map<JsonElement, JsonObject> list, String message) {
        Set<JsonElement> keys = list.keySet();
        for (JsonElement key : keys) { //iterate through the map
            ChannelInboundHandler[] handlers = {
                    new MessageCompletenessHandler(),
                    new MessageRequest(message),
            };
            JsonObject identity = list.get(key);
            ChannelFuture f = connectWithHandler(identity.get("ip").getAsString(), identity.get("port").getAsInt(), handlers); //to the following ip/port send message and return ChannelFuture
        }
        return result; //here result should be a ChannelFuture that when .addListener is added it should be called only when ALL the ChannelFuture-s from the for loop have finished(a.k.a. all messages have been sent)
}
```

The comments should explain the situation clearly enough.
The question is how do I implement this ChannelFuture result.
I know I can .sync() the ChannelFuture-s, but this defeats the purpose of async networking.

P.S.: I essentially want to have the functionality described here https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.2.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.DeferredList.html  but am failing to find an equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general what you're trying to achieve is not really correct async way. However netty has an utility class for that kind of task - [DefaultChannelGroupFuture.java](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/group/DefaultChannelGroupFuture.java). However it is package private and used only for [DefaultChannelGroup.java](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/group/DefaultChannelGroup.java) which indeed does what you described in your code. So you could easily copy this `DefaultChannelGroupFuture` and use it. To be more specific :

```
Collection<ChannelFuture> futures = ArrayList<ChannelFuture>();
...
 //here you add your futures
 ChannelFuture f = connectWithHandler(identity.get("ip").getAsString(), identity.get("port").getAsInt(), handlers); 
 futures.add(f);
...

DefaultChannelGroupFuture groupOfFutures = new DefaultChannelGroupFuture(futures, executor);
if (groupOfFutures.sync().isSuccess()) {
}
```

Have in mind you'll need to change DefaultChannelGroupFuture for your needs.

Comment: You said that this is not really the correct async way to do it. What would be the good netty way to do it?

Comment: What I mean is - waiting for all writes is not a nice way. Maybe you need to think over your logic and consider alternatives where waiting for all writes in not necessary.